# Xamarin Form:-BackgroundImage for content page it's not getting stretch

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have added simple BackgroundImage for content page it's working perfect on all devices. But issue is only on **IOS IPhone XS MAX** image is not getting stretch.And also there is not option for Aspect for backgroundImage.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Demo.Welcome"
             BackgroundImage="bg.png">

  <ContentPage.Content>

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Note- I have checked image rotation and pixel are perfect.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing a custom renderer, you can use a grid layout, due the grid layout can manage z-index, so you can place the image beneath the content. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Demo.Welcome">
    <Grid>
        <Image
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Source="bg.png" />
        <ScrollView>
            <!--
                ...
                Your content here
                ...
            -->
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer. Considering most of us are using grids and not empty pages. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Demo.Welcome">
  <ContentPage.Content>
      <AbsoluteLayout>
         <Image Source="bg.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.,1.,1,1"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="Fill"/>          
      </AbsoluteLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CustomRenderer to set the background image (Adapt to your PageName and namespaces. I've used this to fill images in iOS pages.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Forms.TestPage), typeof(.iOS.Renderers.TestPage))]
namespace Mindflow.Gamification.Mercedes.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class TestPage : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }


            var page = e.NewElement as Mindflow.Gamification.Forms.Pages.Game.GamePage;

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(View.Frame.Size);
            UIImage i = UIImage.FromFile(page.BackgroundImage);
            i = i.Scale(View.Frame.Size);

            View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(i);
        }
    }
}
```